# C# Cast List of base type to list of derived type

Tags: c#, casting

I'm casting list of base type to list of derived type

```
List<TicketDetail> ticketDetails = listResult.Cast<TicketDetail>().ToList();
List<TicketDetail> ticketDetails = listResult.ConvertAll(x => (TicketDetail) x).ToList();
```

I tried both of them and each one of them throws:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WorkOrder.Service.Ticket' to type 'WorkOrder.Service.TicketDetail'.
>   here is my classes

```
namespace WorkOrder.Service
{
    using System;
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(TicketDetail))]
    public partial class Ticket
    {
        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        public long TicketId { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string TicketSource { get; set; }
        public string TicketType { get; set; }
        public string ManagedByGroup { get; set; }
        public string ManagedByUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> SubscriptionId { get; set; }
        public string PriorityLevel { get; set; }
        public string Impact { get; set; }
        public string ImpactOnBusiness { get; set; }
        public string Risk { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PlannedStartDatetime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualStartDatetime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PlannedDeadlineDatetime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualDeadlineDatetime { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TransactionDatetime { get; set; }
        public string AssignedToGroup { get; set; }
        public string AssignedToUser { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public int SourceId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int ManagedByGroupId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ManagedByUserId { get; set; }
        public int AssignedToGroupId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AssignedToUserId { get; set; }
        public int PriorityLevelId { get; set; }
        public int ImpactLevelId { get; set; }
        public int ImpactOnBusinessLevelId { get; set; }
        public int RiskLevelId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

derived class:

```
namespace WorkOrder.Service
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TicketDetail : WorkOrder.Service.Ticket
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<WorkLogView> WorkLogs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant cast base type to derived type unless that object was created as derived type first.... how to fix? use constructor in derived type that takes basetype. if you want a fast way you have to copy these objects one by one. other wise use reflection which is slow.

Comment: OP is using the `KnownType` to do the trick. It might be the service that isn't returning the right type. I am compelled to vote to reopen because of this.

Comment: What does your service code look like? What does the method return? Did you update the service reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not cast from `Ticket` to `TicketDetail`, because `TicketDetail` is a derived type of `Ticket`, but the ather way round is not possible.

You need to create new objects, using the Linq `Select` expression, like:
`listResult.Select(item => new TicketDetail() { /* ... */ }).ToList()`

**EDIT**

To avoid to set all properties in the `Select` expression, create a constructor in `TicketDetail`, which accepts a `Ticket`:

```
namespace WorkOrder.Service
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TicketDetail : WorkOrder.Service.Ticket
    {
        public TicketDetail(Ticket ticket)
        {
             this.StatusId = ticket.StatusId;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<WorkLogView> WorkLogs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then just do:

```
List<TicketDetail> ticketDetails = listResult.Select(item => new TicketDetail(item)).ToList()
```

Comment: I think you meant "derived type" instead of "instance".  Instance is used to describe the relationship between an object and it's type, not between two types.